# Storing access token globally, re-loading when expires it a thread-safe way

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, synchronization, json.net

I have an API client that connects to a 3rd party API service.

The problem is I first have to authenticate, and then I get an expiring token that I use.

How can I use my API in my ASP.NET MVC application, and also keep track if the token expires I have to re-authenticate and then make the API call that failed (when the token expires).

```
List<User> users = api.getUsers();
```

If the api clients token expires, it has to re-authenticate and then make the call.  Is there a way to re-call api.getUsers after it re-authenticates because intially the call will fail with "expired token".

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

If there is service call that allows validating the token, have your authentication object check the token in the getter and authenticate anytime it is not valid.

If not, I would use a try/catch and handle the expired token exception by authenticating and repeating the request. The repeat either needs to be a stand-alone block of code in the catch or you need an object to check the last time authenticate was called and throw an exception after n attempts.

I'm sure there are several other approaches, these are what come immediately to mind.

Comment: the problem is I don't want to repeat this in every api call method, trying to think of a pattern to do this in a single place.

Comment: The services require a token, so with getToken method that checks if the token is valid and returns a valid token, you will have a single method to call for authenticating. It can be expanded to take parameters to perform this for all of your code that needs a token.